# Argument is different to argument

Tags: xamarin.forms

This is in a constructor...

```
MessagingCenter.Unsubscribe<object, AppointmentDetail>(this, "AppointmentLoaded");
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<object, AppointmentDetail>(this, "AppointmentLoaded", async (sender, a) =>
{
    if (appointment.AppointmentId == a.AppointmentId && appointment != a) // a member property
    {
        ...
    }
});
```

This is called in the same page...

```
MessagingCenter.Send<object, AppointmentDetail>(this, "AppointmentLoaded", appointment);
```

The handler function is called and the appointment sent with the notification is different to the appointment that arrives at the handler.

How is that possible?

Additionally, the handler runs *twice* even though the message is only sent once.

Any ideas?

If I put a breakpoint on the message send, then it runs correctly. So I'm guessing there's some debugging artifact at play.

Comment: Create a dedicated message object and ensure that you are subscribing only once.

Answer (score 0):

This was happening because I'd created two pages, one either side of a login process, and the first page was still receiving messages.